# How to add Button over image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

i am new in CSS so sorry if this question is just stupid or too simple but i just dont know how to do it.

I need to place a button over the image, how it should looks:
[image]

You see there a blue button  "Kopit" Thats IT! i style this thing already to my website but as one single image so my code looks like:

CSS:

```
#shop{
    background-image: url("images/shop_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    height:121px;
    width: 984px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 13px;
}

#shop .content{    
    width: 182px; /*328 co je 1/3 - 20margin left*/
    height: 121px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right:0px;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

My HTML:

```
 <div id="shop">
      <div class="content"> Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <a href="#"><img src="images/CSsteam.png"></a></div>
      <div class="content"> Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <a href="#"><img src="images/CSsteam.png"></a></div>
      <div class="content"> Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <a href="#"><img src="images/CSsteam.png"></a></div>
      <div class="content"> Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <a href="#"><img src="images/CSsteam.png"></a></div>
      <div class="content"> Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam <a href="#"><img src="images/CSsteam.png"></a></div>         
  </div>
```

Is here anybody who can help me to style that button as a different element?

Thanks a lot for reading this post.

Comment: Well, apart from CSS you will need a button in the first place. Currently, there is a link surrounding the entire image. Is that you intention, that the whole image is clickable? Or just the button?

Comment: I try something like: #shop .buybutton{
    background-color: #2d79bd;
    width:58px;
    height:22px;
}

Comment: Yes, but you need an element with class `buybutton` in the html for that to work. A website isn't *just* CSS. CSS just adds a style to the existing elements. To make a red chair, you don't need just red paint, you also need a chair. CSS is just the paint.

Comment: Ofc mate i had it in HTML as well but it just didnt work as i want so i delete it to not confuse ppl who try to help

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I would change the HTML to something like this:

```
<div id="shop">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/182x121"/> 
        <a href="#">Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I would be able to use `position:absolute` and `position:relative` to force the blue button down.

I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9w99/

Answer (score 12):

Adapt this example to your code

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-holder">
    <img src="images/img-1.png" alt="image description"/>
    <a class="link" href=""></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-holder {position: relative;}
.img-holder .link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; /*your button position*/
    right: 10px; /*your button position*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give `relative` or `absolute` or `fixed` positioning to your container (`#shop`) and set its `zIndex` to say 100.

You also need to give say `relative` positioning to your elements with the class `content` and  lower `zIndex` say 97.

Do the above-mentioned with your images too and set their `zIndex` to 91.

And then position your button higher by setting its position to `absolute` and `zIndex` to 95

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JaP7T/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="shop">

 <div class="content"> Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam 

     <img src="http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif">

         <a href="#"><span class='span'><span></a>

     </div>

 <div class="content"> Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam 

     <img src="http://www.openvms.org/images/samples/130x130.gif">

         <a href="#"><span class='span'><span></a>

     </div>

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#shop{
    background-image: url("images/shop_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;    
    height:121px;
    width: 984px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 13px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100
}

#shop .content{    
    width: 182px; /*328 co je 1/3 - 20margin left*/
    height: 121px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    margin-right:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:97

}

img{

    position:relative;
    z-index:91

}

.span{

    width:70px;
    height:40px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:95;
    right:60px;
    bottom:-20px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like TryingToImprove's answer. I've essentially taken his answer and simplified it down to the **barebones** css to accomplish the same thing. I think it's a lot easier to chew on.

```css
.content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.content a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="http://unsplash.it/182/121" />
  <a href="#">Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content"> 
  Counter-Strike 1.6 Steam 
     <img src="images/CSsteam.png">
     <a href="#">Koupit</a>
</div>

/*Use this css*/
content {
width: 182px; /*328 co je 1/3 - 20margin left*/
height: 121px;
line-height: 20px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 9px;
margin-right:0px;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}
content a{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
position:absolute;
bottom:10px;
right:10px;
}
```